# Repeating the indefinite article with differing adjectives?

Tags: grammar, articles

After that event, I became a more heartful, a soulful, a fearless, a self-contained person

OR

After that event, I became a more heartful, soulful, fearless, self-contained person

By the way, can we use "a, an" before comparative adjectives as above, like "a more beautiful person"? we can say "a better idea, a taller guy" etc but about with "more"?

Also, why do we say "his best grade was BA" but not use also "the" as usual before superlative as in "his the best grade was BA"?

Comment: You actually can say "_a more beautiful person_"! In fact, the comparative form of _beautiful_ is actually **more beautiful**! Some adjectives work this way: you can't always put the suffix "_-er_" in front of an adjective to make it comparative. And as you said, since you can say "_a better idea_" and "_a taller guy_", you can also say "_a **more beautiful** person_" because it is also a comparative adjective!

Comment: *Also, why do we say "his best grade was BA" but not use also "the" as usual before superlative as in "his the best grade was BA"?*  Where have you seen this sentence?  A "BA" is usually a *degree*, not a *grade*, and we would say it is someone's *highest* degree, not his *best*.  Also "his the best grade" doesn't make any sense; *grade* is a countable noun, so it needs a determiner, but *his* and *the* are both determiners, and you can't have two.

Answer (score 1):

"I became a more heartful, soulful, fearless, self-contained person" is more common.

If you wanted to use some variation of the first option you provided, you should use a parallel construction by inserting more every time as well (this would really emphasise the transition:
- "I became a more heartful, a **more** soulful, a **more** fearless, (and) a **more** self-contained person"

If they were nouns, a sentence similar to option 1 would work fine:
- "He was a rogue, a ruffian, and a traitor."